# CallKit incomming call hide to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, callkit

I have a VoIP application.
I implement CallKit in it.
I build it in Xcode 10.3

Sometimes it happens that the incoming call is hidden.
Only for iOS13.
It is not possible to answer the call.

In iOS 12, the callkit flashes, but then appears.

Application was not closed by system.
And ringing continues to play.
Double click on the home button to open CallKit screen.

For all call create a new NSUUID with: [NSUUID UUID]

Please can you advise me?

Comment: Yes, but I build in xcode 10.3, system does not close the application in this case.

Comment: Same happens to me also , Need to reopen from app stack with double tap on home button. this seems iOS bug

Comment: Everytime you report incoming call, try a new UUID. It can be a problem if you report the same UUID that previously failed to present

Comment: Yes, for all call get new UUID. Create a new NSUUID with: [NSUUID UUID]

Comment: Is it possible to handle this issue ?

Comment: So far I have not found a solution.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan Any solution you guys found so far? Im facing the same issue?

Comment: @MudassirZulfiqar No. still i couldn't figure it out this issue. Anybody have suggestion for this ?

Here's my question about this issue : [https://stackoverflow.com/q/59840370/4014369]